# How to set in C/C++ Windows audio ducking behaviour?

Tags: windows, winapi, audio, registry

I am trying to achieve inside a C/C++ application the setting that is established by this dialog of Windows 10:

**Control Panel > Sound > Communications > When Windows detects communications activity > Do nothing**

[image]

I found that this specific setting is stored in Windows Registry at  *Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Multimedia\Audio*, value *"UserDuckingPreference" = 00000003*

I verified that opening Windows Registry Editor (regedit) and setting that key value to 00000003 **IS NOT ENOUGH** to effect the behaviour.
By changing the registry that way I even notice that the referred Control Panel dialog displays the change done (i.e. shows the fourth option has been selected) **BUT** the desired ducking behaviour is not effectively enforced in Windows.

Changing this setting normally inside the Control Panel dialog and pressing Apply is what really enforces the desired behaviour.

Up to this point I am executing this code in my C/C++ application:

```
      // ...
      TCHAR lszValue[255];
      HKEY hKey;
      DWORD dwType = REG_SZ;
      DWORD dwSize = 255;
      DWORD dwValue;
      LRESULT lres;

      lres = RegOpenKeyExA(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, _T("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Multimedia\\Audio"), 0L, KEY_WRITE, &hKey);

      dwValue = 3;      // Set to 3 for "do nothing"
      lres = RegSetValueExA(
         hKey,
         TEXT("UserDuckingPreference"),
         0,
         REG_DWORD,
         (LPBYTE)&dwValue,
         sizeof(DWORD));

      lres = RegCloseKey(hKey);
      // ...
```

The code above makes the due changes in the Registry value, but it is not effective in audio. 
What is missing in the code after setting the Registry value?

All I want to achieve is to be able to configure the Windows settings as if I were acting on the GUI dialog of Control Panel as shown in the question.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you ruled out `WM_SETTINGCHANGE`?  (e.g. use a toy program with a top-level window, handle `WM_SETTINGCHANGE`, and log when you receive it and with what arguments.  Have that program running and use the official control panel to change the setting.)

Comment: With `ISimpleAudioVolume`, `IChannelAudioVolume`, and `IAudioStreamVolume` interfaces you can control the volume levels of [audio sessions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/coreaudio/audio-sessions), which are collections of shared-mode audio streams. See [Session Volume Controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/coreaudio/session-volume-controls) and [AudioSessionVolume](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/blob/44d192fd7ec6f2422b7d023891c5f805ada2c811/Samples/Win7Samples/multimedia/mediafoundation/MFPlayer2/AudioSessionVolume.cpp).

Comment: If I understood them well, the comments above will help me to change the behavior of a given application (in its source code) to not duck its audio, even when receiving an event/message from Windows. 

But what I want to do is just forcing Windows to not generate any events triggered by 
 detection of communications activity. In simple words I want to effect by my code the system configuration that can be achieved by the Control Panel dialog shown in my question.

Comment: @JulioCabezas: My comment was related to the system setting.  On the other hand, that system setting is designed for the user, and you shouldn't be messing with it, unless the user has specifically requested that behavior (and you've given them a configuration option for your application NOT to mess with their control panel choice).

Comment: @BenVoigt:  I agree with your considerations. Now it is the case that the user requests/allows the application to affect the said Windows audio ducking configuration. Also the application has a configuration option to turn on/off that behaviour.
That being said what is missing in my code is some code to interact with WinAPI to put in effect the registry changes just made. What do you suggest?

Comment: @JulioCabezas: `WM_SETTINGCHANGE` is the mechanism that the control panels use to tell running applications and other system components that a setting changed.  That's why I mentioned it.